# OpenVZ - Ubuntu 14 DESKTOP GUI

Tags: openvz

There any way to install a **GUI desktop** in Ubuntu 14 **OpenVZ**?

Comment: To be honest, if you want a GUI, why are you useing openvz? Sure you can do it, but IMO KVM is a better option and openvz is not so light weight is you are going to install a DE such as Gnome or KDE ;)

Answer (score 1):

I used [this tutorial](http://internetlifeforum.com/linux-forums/191-how-install-free-ubuntu-lxde-desktop-vps/) to install LXDE. Its much more lightweight than Gnome desktop.

Also i tried Faizans tutorial mentioned on this page, but failed. There was no beautiful graphical interface, just terminal, at the end [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-14-04) helped to launch xfce4. But this installation is extremelly heavy, around 3 times larger than LXDE.

Answer (score 0):

Execute following commands one by one

```
sudo su
apt-get update
apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
apt-get install gnome-core gnome-session-fallback
```

Configure the Gnome Desktop Manager and XServer

```
service gdm start
dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Install VNC software

```
sudo apt-get install vnc4server
```

XFCE

```
apt-get update
apt-get install xfce4 xfce4-goodies tightvncserver
```

Start VNC server

```
vncserver :1 -geometry 1024x768 -depth 16 -pixelformat rgb565
```

Now you will be able to connect to ubuntu VPS with VNC.

On ubuntu, it won't start "vncconfig" on booting. You need to run "vncconfig" to share clip board between vnc.

```
vncconfig
```

You will get a terminal window on login. You can start gui application from this window. It use less CPU. If you need genome desktop, edit file

```
vi /root/.vnc/xstartup
```

Find

```
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &
```

Replace with

```
xterm -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
gnome-session --session=gnome-classic &
```

Kill VNC Process

```
vncserver -kill :1
```